# Using addSubView or presentModalViewController in a standard method with paramaters?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to reuse code, I have some tutorial view controllers / views, which I would like to call from an action sheet. However, the calling views are different. Sometimes the tutorial view(s) would need to be added as a subview and sometimes they would be added to the navigation controller.

How can I expand my standard function to cater for these two different situations ?

You can see what I'm having to do instead, which means duplicate code :(

I have a class called which holds the standard code, I want to add calls to views here directly.

```
-(void)showHelpClickButtonAtIndex:(int)buttonIndex:(UIView *)vw {
if (buttonIndex == CommonUIHelpPagesBtnIdx) {
    // do nothing
} else if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Tutorial here");
}
}
```

I use in one view like this ...

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet 
      clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
CommonUI *cui = [CommonUI alloc];
[cui showHelpClickButtonAtIndex:buttonIndex:self.view];
[cui release];

if (buttonIndex == CommonUIHelpPagesBtnIdx) {
    UIViewController *theController = [[HelpViewController alloc] 
         initWithNibName:@"HelpView" 
         bundle:nil onPage:HelpPageCalcBalance];
    [self.navigationController.topViewController 
         presentModalViewController:theController animated:YES];
    [theController release];
   }
}
```

And is another view like this...

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet 
     clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
   [cui showHelpClickButtonAtIndex:buttonIndex:self.view];

   if (buttonIndex == CommonUIHelpPagesBtnIdx) {
        theController = [[HelpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelpView"                     
        bundle:nil onPage:HelpPageGettingStarted];

        [self.view addSubview:theController.view];
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the actionSheets could share one same delegate that would be a root viewController or the appDelegate that would know what to do according to it's current state. Hence the same actionSheet method would be used in both case.

If you put your appDelegate which can always be reached as the actionSheetDelegate, you should be able to gain control on every way to present your view, either modally or not in any of your views + the window.

EDIT (re-Edited with your code): Maybe try this

MyAppDelegate.h:

```
@interface MyAppAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>
(...)

- (void) showHelp;
```

MyAppDelegate.m:

```
- (void) showHelp {
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" 
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles: @"Tutorial", @"Help Pages", nil];

    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
    [actionSheet showInView:window];
    [actionSheet release];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == CommonUIHelpPagesBtnIdx) {
        UIViewController *theController = [HelpViewController alloc];
        if ([[self lvc] superview] != nil) {
            theController = [initWithNibName:@"HelpView"                     
                                      bundle:nil
                                      onPage:HelpPageGettingStarted];
            [window addSubview:theController.view];
        } else {
            theController = [initWithNibName:@"HelpView"
                                      bundle:nil
                                      onPage:HelpPageCalcBalance];
            UINavigationController * navController = [tabBarController selectedViewController];
            [navController.topViewController presentModalViewController:theController animated:YES];
        }
        [theController release];
    }
}
```

and in your viewControllers:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    MyAppDelegate *delegate = (MyAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
    [infoButton addTarget:delegate
                   action:@selector(showHelp)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     UIBarButtonItem *infoItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton];
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = infoItem;
     [infoItem release];
 }
```

Didn't try it but it should work.

Comment: From your code, I believe the calling viewController sends itself as a parameter for being the delegate, maybe if you try not doing this and always use the same delegate like your appDelegate this could help.

Comment: If this is the same kind of issue as your tabBar issue, if you set up your ApplicationDelegate as being a UIActionSheetDelegate as well and you set it as the delegate ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]), it could respond to your actionSheets method and know what to do.  Either show the view in the window or pushing (modally or not) the view in the navigationController's topViewController that it would retrieve from the tabBarController's selected tab.

Comment: You actually lost me, could you clarify what the problem is or even post your code somewhere so I could have a look on it?

Comment: Ok got your code working, I can't see your tabBar problem, but I believe you wish to avoid having your code duplicated. So one way could be to have your info button above every views in your window and manage everything from your delegate, you'll have to be aware of what tab is selected in order to hide it when needed. One other way (I believe easier) is to have your appDelegate be the target of your info button so that it takes care of the info button actions and action Sheet response

Comment: done, I didn't try it so there might be typos. At least this could be an idea